# Add a index key to existing array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a array, which I need to check if it's associative or not.

The array can look like this:

```
[preview] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => web
                [side] => left
            )
        [1] => Array
           (
               [type] => web
               [side] => right

           )
      )
```

And that is perfect. But sometimes, I get this:

```
   [preview_file] => Array
       (
        [type] => artwork
        [side] => right
       )
```

In this case, I need to add a index of `0` to make the array look like this:

```
    [preview_file] => Array
       (
        [0] => Array
          (
           [type] => artwork
           [side] => right
          )

       )
```

I'm using this function to check if it's assoctiative:

```
 function is_assoc($array) {
     return (bool)count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string'));
 }
```

If not, I need to somehow add the `[0]`. Doe=s anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the values instead of the keys. It also sounds like you can get away just checking the first value:

```
function is_assoc($array) {
  return is_array(reset($array));
}
```

Was your question about how to make the actual change? This ought to work:

```
if (!is_assoc($preview)) {
  $preview = array($preview);
}
```

Comment: This works except i still have the original one in there as well so its both the one without a index and one with a index

Answer (score 1):

Different way:

```
if(!isset($array[0])) {
    $array[0] = $array;
}
```